# Remove Everything and Reinstall Windows on a different drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-installation, reinstall

In Windows 10, there is an option to "remove everything and reinstall Windows."  However, in my experience, whenever I use this option, Windows gets re-installed to the same drive that it was previously on.  What if I want to instead install it on another drive?  What's the easiest way to do this?

The main reason I ask is because I don't have access to the original installation media anymore, and I am concerned with running into license validity issues if I don't do it properly.  What's the best way to move it to another drive?

Comment: Windows 10 ISOs are free, as free as air, so download the current ISO and install Windows 10 to the drive you want it installed to

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid license, you should have no issues reinstalling Windows 10 on the same machine.

[Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) the Windows installation media from Microsoft.

During the install, there is an `Advanced` option where you can delete your old Windows install, as well as select the drive you want to install it on.

As a reminder, backup anything you need before you proceed.

Comment: Thank you for the information; I was successfully able to install Windows 10 on my other drive.  However, I left my old installation on the previous drive, and I notice that when I boot into either of them, they both say "Windows is activated with a digital license."  Is that supposed to be the case?  I can have multiple Windows installs on the same computer (on different drives) with both using the same license?  I'm just wanting to make sure that I did this correctly.